# Tiamat splash and Infinite Duress (Warwick ultimate)

Tags: league-of-legends

The wikia entry for [Tiamat](http://leagueoflegends.wikia.com/wiki/Tiamat) specifically mentions that it does 50% of **physical** damage as splash. It also gives Infinite Duress (Warwick's R) as an exception, without mentioning further details.

- Does this mean that items which add on-hit magic damage (Wits' End, Malady) do not contribute to the splash?
- How does it work with **Warwick**'s ultimate? Specifically, Tiamat splashes ***physical*** damage done while Duress does ***magic*** damage - so will Tiamat proc splash but with 0 dmg (no physical component) unless there is a Sheen equipped? If not, is the splash also magic (as per original source) or its converted into physical dmg?
- If Tiamat splashes during Duress, since it is using a magic damage source will that add on-hit effects from e.g. Wits' even if this is not normally the case?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Infinite Duress states :

> "Warwick lunges at an enemy champion, suppressing the target for 1.8
>   seconds and striking for **magic damage** five times in 0.334-second
>   intervals. Warwick gains 30% life steal for the duration. Each of his
>   strikes triggers on-hit effects and benefits from life steal and
>   Eternal Thirst."

The first thing we note is that Infinite Duress does magic damage. Magic damage does not get splashed by Tiamat but let us continue.

Note the third sentence that modifies these magic damage strikes:

> Each of his strikes triggers on-hit effects and benefits from life steal and Eternal
>   Thirst."

Here we find that the ability modifies how life steal and on-hit effects (such as Wit's End, Malady, Bloodrazor) are applied. However it still do NOT make the damage he deals physical. Tiamat will only be proced on physical damage dealt from basic attacks, it will **NOT** cause any damage from his ultimate to be splashed for the follwoing reasons:

1) Infinite Duress deals magic damage (Tiamat only splashes physical damage).

2) Infinite Duress makes specific reference to applying on-hit effects but does not actually make the strikes from the ability count as basic attacks or deal physical damage (Tiamat only splashes on physical damage from basic attacks).

Answer (score 2):

Infinite Duress applies on hit affects.  It will work with all on hit items.  Madred's, Malady, Whits End, and even Frozen mallet.

The splash is considered an on-hit effect, and thus will be triggered by basic attacks and abilities that proc on-hit effects, such as Gangplank's Parrrley, Ezreal's Mystic Shot, Warwick's Infinite Duress, Twitch's Spray and Pray or Fiora's Blade Waltz.   From the lol wiki.  http://leagueoflegends.wikia.com/wiki/Tiamat

It will proc them, but I think since his ult is magical it will not do much...

Answer (score 0):

Warwicks' Infinite Duress is a suppression effect that applies his passive at full stacks for the duration, applies lifesteal and other on-hit effects five times over the course of the 1.8 seconds  of the suppression. So yes, unless Tiamats says otherwise about that specific ability, it does procc on Infinite Duress.

Comment: Problem is that Duress does ***magic*** damage, while Tiamat splashes 50% of ***physical*** - and the note about an 'exception' doesn't give any details.

Comment: But Infinite Duress states that it procs On-Hit effects. Tiamats procs on hit. Scroll further down the page to after it discusses stacking Tiamats, and you'll see what I am talking about.

Comment: As a side note, it also splashes a Sheen procced auto attack WITH the Sheen proc, which is also magic damage, as well as Madred's Bloodrazor and Wriggle's/Madred's Razor

Comment: It stacks with Madred's?? Sheen does physical, but Madred is magic dmg.

Comment: (deleted old comment I had forgotten I'd started typing) No it doesn't. I played around with it some more last night. However, Tiamat procs with Infinite Duress (as per the first part of your question) as it is an On-Hit effect, and Infinite Duress procs all On-Hit effects as stated in the wiki. Tiamats is an on-hit effect. Tiamats WILL NOT proc Wit's End, etc. because it cannot, according to its own description. If a Champions' ability states that it procs On-Hit effects, then Tiamats procs off it (as the Wiki states).